# Custom themes in emacs 24.2.1 on Windows causing error

Tags: windows, emacs, themes

So I have been able to install custom themes on my mac and linux machines, but am unable to get custom themes to work on my emacs windows installation.

I am able to add the below to my ~/.emacs file without problems:

```
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes")
```

When I put the command below into the ~/.emacs file:

```
(load-theme 'tomorrow-night t)
```

it is able to find the file just fine, but it stops with the following error:

```
Symbol's value as variable is void: <!--
```

I have tested this with multiple different themes (not just tomorrow-theme) and the same problem occurs, but all other plugins and additions to emacs work just fine.

Any help would be appreciated since I would enjoy to have all of my different machines have the same theming style in emacs.

Just to note, I am using Windows 8.

Comment: What's in that file? Looks like it contains an HTML-style comment.

Comment: [link](https://github.com/chriskempson/tomorrow-theme/blob/master/GNU%20Emacs/tomorrow-night-theme.el), it doesn't sadly, that would be a nice easy fix if that was the case.

Comment: I figured out the problem, when saving a .el file with the extension .el rather than .el.txt in windows 8, it will add html tags automatically around every line. This happened with chrome and selecting the raw text and then C-s.

Comment: Just tried it with Firefox and Chrome (and a file on emacswiki.org) on Windows 7, and I don't see it happening. It's hard to believe that Chrome's behavior in that regard would be different on Windows 8. Could you have been saving an actual HTML page? For example, on EmacsWiki, when you want to save a file, you need to click on "Download" first, and then save the resulting plain text page.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, turns out saving .el files in windows 8 has some interesting and strange side effects. Look at comment 3 for solution.